# Interaction between two tables that aren't linked

Tags: sql, database, oracle, command, oracle-apex

I have the 3 following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Flight
(   
    ID_Flight number (10) not null,
    Status varchar (50) not null,
    Price varchar (10) not null,
    Boarding date,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_Flight)
)

CREATE TABLE Stopover
(
    ID_Stopover number (10) not null,
    ID_Flight number,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_Stopover),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Flight) REFERENCES Flight (ID_Flight)
)

CREATE TABLE Ticket
(
    ID_Ticket number (10),
    ID_Stopover number,
    Seat varchar (5) not null,
    Price varchar (10) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_Ticket),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Stopover) REFERENCES Stopover (ID_Stopover)
)
```

As you can see, both tables Flight and Ticket have an column called "Price". Notice that the table that is the link between Flight and Ticket is the Stopover one. ID_Stopover is a FK in Ticket and ID_Flight is a FK in Stopover. 
My goal here is to import, somehow, the values from the column Price (Flight) to Price (Ticket).
Something like this:

```
ID_Flight -> 1 | Price (Flight) -> $100,99
ID_Flight -> 2 | Price (Flight) -> $350,00
ID_Flight -> 3 | Price (Flight) -> $1000,00

ID_Ticket -> 1 | Price (Ticket) -> $350,00 (same value from ID_Flight 2)
ID_Ticket -> 2 | Price (Ticket) -> $350,00 (same value from ID_Flight 2)
ID_Ticket -> 7 | Price (Ticket) -> $100,00 (same value from ID_Flight 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) to update your table based on values of linked tables:

```
merge into ticket t
using ( select *
        from stopOver 
          inner join flight 
            using(id_flight)
      ) sub
on (t.ID_Stopover = sub.ID_Stopover)
when matched then
  update set price = sub.price
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aleksej! It really helped me solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (
select f.id_flight, 
       t.id_ticket, 
       f.price flight_price, 
       t.price ticket_price
from flight f, ticket t, stopover s
where f.id_flight = s.id_flight 
and t.id_stopover = s.id_stopover
)
where id_flight = &x
```